# How to update DataTables DOM?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net) for a review system, An user can grade each item by clicking on stars(1 to 5).

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tabela-disciplinas-preferencia">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Semestre</th>
            <th>Curso</th>
            <th>Disciplina</th>
            <th>Nível de Interesse</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Engenharia de Software</td>
        <td>Redes</td>
        <td>    
            <div class="rating" valor="0">
                <span valor="5">☆</span><span valor="4">☆</span><span valor="3">☆</span><span valor="2">☆</span><span valor="1">☆</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
     ....
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabela-disciplinas-preferencia').dataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
    } );
});
```

However when an user click to grade one item, I change valor attribute in rating div but datatables doesn't update their values internally.

Click rating event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.rating span').click(function(){
        starR= new StarRating( $(this).parent());
        starR.changeValue($(this).attr('valor'));
        //Get TR Element
         aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( $(this).parent().parent().get(0) );
         aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
         //Get rating div
         rating = aData[3];
         aData[3] = $(rating).attr('valor', $(this).attr('valor'));
         // ????
         oTable.fnUpdate(aData[3]);          

    });
});
```

How can I update datatables DOM? I already got data and changed value but how can I update back to oTable?

Comment: What star rating plugin are you using?What do you mean with "the DOM is not updated"?

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I am not using star rating plugin, It's just css. I mean that datatables data is not same as my document html

Comment: Of course it's not, dataTables create a tabel object and it keeps the object updated. I thought you used a plugin beacuse i was trying to make a fiddle to replicate this and this line starR= new StarRating( $(this).parent()); gives an error. If you create a fiddle i'll try to help you

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I already managed to update it, thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing values and inserting back to aData already update oTable

```
$('div.rating span').click(function(){
        starR= new StarRating($(this).parent());
        starR.changeValue($(this).attr('valor'));
        //update oTable row data
        aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( $(this).parent().parent().get(0) );
        aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
        aData[3] = $(aData[3]).attr('valor', starR.getValue());

    });
```

That's solution I have found and seems working pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a minute, but a simple alternative.

```
$('div.rating span').click(function () {
    //Invalidate Row after DOM manipulation
    var parentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    $('#your-table').DataTable().row(parentRow).invalidate().draw();
}
```

You can invalidate row(s) or column(s) that have been changed and the table will update itself. This method will keep search criteria intact.

Comment: It's been a bit since I had to look at this code, but my first guess is that your DataTable is re-querying to display it's state again. Might want to experiment with saving state before invalidating.